# IIS URL Rewrite need to redirect and rewrite URL

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, arr

I want users to be able to:

- go to "https://webserver1.acme.com/UserManagement2" and hit the Tomcat application on a different server: "https://10.0.0.7:9443/UserManagement"

What does work is this:

- go to "https://webserver1.acme.com/UserManagement" and hit the Tomcat application on a different server: "https://10.0.0.7:9443/UserManagement"

This rule does not seem to work and directs me to a blank page:

```
<rules>
<rule name="UMSRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/UserManagement2" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://10.0.0.7:9443/UserManagement" appendQueryString="true" 
    logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
```

`

Comment: 1. You need to install ARR and configure the reverse proxy rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing 2. Enable FRT to troubleshoot, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have ARR with reverse proxy configured. This one works, where I specify the actual app URI (/UserManagement) as a condition and I add {R:1} to the rewrite URL. I just can't use an alias in the condition (e.g., /UserManagement2). This rule work: <rules>
<rule name="UMSRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/UserManagement" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="https://10.0.0.7:9443/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" 
    logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
</rules>

Comment: If you found the solution, you should post and accept your own answer.

Comment: I have not found the answer but I will post it for sure. I am trying to figure out the correct rewrite syntax if I want to connect to: https://webserver.com/UserManagement2 (IIS) which is proxy for a back-end Tomcat application on https://10.0.0.7:9443/UserManagement. The URL rewrite rule which has an alias of "/UserManagement2" does not work.

Comment: Using the failed request trace to see the detailed request process should help you solve the problem.